# LDAP Queries from batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ldap

This is my first post so please be gentle!

I work for a company that utilises SCCM 2012. During the process of imaging a Windows 10 laptop, you are required to delete objects from Active Directory and the Software Configuration Console, this is in order for the device to be added to the domain during the task sequence and to be added to the unknown devices collection and be offered a new operating system during PE boot.

I found that manually finding each individual machine was very repetitive and so I developed a combination of .bat and .ps1 scripts to aid me.

I'm hoping that by posing the question here, I might be able to find a better, or perhaps more efficient way of doing this. Or alternatively, help someone who does a similar job to myself.

The script writes an LDAP query, logs the device name, technician name, and the date / time of day to a server share path. The filename of the log file is numbered by week. There is REM'd comments for you to use as the true date and replaces the "/" in the standard windows format.

Begin "query_writer.bat" code;

```
@echo off

REM This changes the default delimiter using the "DATE" command to "_" instead of "/"
REM It caused the script to be unable to find the specified path.
REM Added path to S: drive as a variable.
REM DEPRECEATED VARIABLES.
REM set datefix=%DATE%
REM set datefix=%DATE:/=_%

REM %weeknum% replaces %DATE%. Logs are now done by week, not day.
REM Similarly archiving now works on a weekly basis.

powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File get_week.ps1
set /p weeknum=<temp.file
set /A lastweek=%weeknum%-1
echo %lastweek%

IF EXIST "[Drive-Letter]:\[path-to-log-file]\device_log_"%lastweek%.txt (
    archive_logs.ps1
    echo. Logs have been archived.
    goto StartQuery
    )

:StartQuery

REM Firstly, delete file "query.txt" to ensure to previous data from script run is deleted.
echo ---Deleting old query file---
echo.
IF EXIST query.txt ( del query.txt )

REM Echo (with no new lines or spaces) the 1st part of the LDAP query.
echo ---Writing first query section to file...---
echo|set /p="(&(objectCategory=computer)(|" >> query.txt
echo.

REM Begin the clever stuff; a nested loop.
REM 1st loop will read each line in "list.txt" before proceeding
REM 2nd loop will take the individual string and add special characters of the LDAP query.
echo ---Writing your LDAP query for multiple devices to file...---
for /F %%i in (list.txt) DO (
    echo %%i by %USERNAME% on %date% at %time% >> "[Drive-Letter]:\[path-to-log-file]\device_log_"%weeknum%.txt
    for %%j in (%%i) do (
        echo|set /p=^(name=%%i^)>> query.txt
        )
    )
echo.

echo ---Writing last query section to file...---
echo|set /p=") )" >> query.txt
echo.
REM for troubleshooting.

Echo Script is completed, press any key to close this command prompt...
pause >nul
:EOF
```

End "query_writer.bat" code.

Begin "get_week.ps1" code;

```
$date=(Get-Date -UFormat %V) ; $date|Out-File -FilePath temp.file -Encoding string -NoNewline
```

End "get_week.ps1" code.

Begin "archive_logs.ps1" code;

```
$date=(Get-Date -UFormat %V)
$file="device_log_$date.txt" ; $destination="Drive-Letter]:\[path-to-log-file]"
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$destination\archives" -Path "$destination\$file" -CompressionLevel Fastest -Confirm
```

End "archive_logs.ps1" code.

Please note, this code is not complete. If anyone has any suggestions to make it better, please let me know. Alternatively, if there is part of it you could use, please be my guest to copy and reproduce.

Best,
Swift

Comment: Rewrite your batch script in PowerShell.

Comment: And what purpose would that serve over my current script which only relies on Powershell when it needs to?

Comment: I understand that you raise a valid point, but I curious why you would ask me to re-write it in Powershell?

Comment: You have no direct code problem or question.  This is really off topic for StackOverFlow.  You would be better off posting this question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Because it will make your life *a lot* simpler. Not only won't your code be scattered across different files, but the code would also be both more compact and more readable.

Comment: I think what everyone is getting at, @Swift, is that if you rewrote it in Powershell (maybe made your own module out of it, too) it would make your life a lot easier when it comes to troubleshooting.  Modularizing your code with specific tasks for specific functions is great because whenever there's a breakdown you know exactly where to look.  I'll reference [this post](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Building-A-PowerShell-Module/) a million times before I die.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, @Squashman, I will certainly post there and see what advice people can offer me.

Comment: Well, the reason it's scattered across multiple files is because it is half-modular. I think it's perfectly reasonable to call a powershell command from a batch script. Especially when it's for something as simple as getting the week of the year (UFormat %V). Perhaps there is a cmdlet in powershell I could use that negate some of my code. I will look into it :)

Comment: I would like to point out that although this code is very complicated, and seems to do a lot, it really only writes a few strings to text files.

The only reason I'm invoking powershell commands is because "Date" command does not support a similar "UFormat %V" function. And without adding 3rd party software onto a device, like 7zip, I cannot compress the archive files.

Whilst I agree, it would be a lot neater with a single language, I'm really still only using batch, except I invoke some other commands in Powershell as DOS doesn't support the feature I need.

Comment: I do have a direct code problem. I'm asking for the best way to approach what I have written. Please read the entire post as it does clearly state that.

Comment: In the third paragraph I said "I'm hoping that by posing the question here, I might be able to find a better, or perhaps more efficient way of doing this. Or alternatively, help someone who does a similar job to myself."